# In what the fact that there is a continuous operator $E:W^{1,p}(U)\to W^{1,p}(\mathbb R^n)$ is important?

Tags: real-analysis, sobolev-spaces

Let $U$ bounded s.t. $\partial U$ is $\mathcal C^1$ Let $V$ a bounded open set such that $U\subset \subset V$. Then there is a bounded linear operator $$E:W^{1,p}(U)\longrightarrow W^{1,p}(\mathbb R^n),$$
s.t. for all $u\in W^{1,p}(U)$ we have

1) $Eu=u$ a.e. in $U$

2) $Eu$ has support within $V$

3) $\|Eu\|_{W^{1,p}(\mathbb R^n)}\leq C\|u\|_{W^{1,p}(U)}$.

My teacher said that this important is very important, but I don't understand in what it's important, neither what it exactly implies. So any explanation would be appreciated.

Comment: It says you can extend $W^{1,p}$ functions to the rest of $\Bbb R^n$, only adding a little bit to their support. This comes up a lot when you use Sobolev spaces for PDE BVPs.

Comment: @Ian: Thank you for your answer. Could you please develop your answer ? For example, in what the continuity of $E$ is important ? By the way, in what the fact that $E$ is linear is important ? Because any function $E:W^{1,p}(U)\to W^{1,p}(\mathbb R^n)$ prolonge a function from to $W^{1,p}(U)$ in a function in $W^{1,p}(\mathbb R^n)$. Thank you

Comment: Again it comes back to what you're doing with the result. The most basic Sobolev space result that is really about PDEs that I can think of is the trace theorem, which basically tells you that Dirichlet BVPs on nice enough domains, posed in Sobolev space, make sense. The proof of that uses this result.

Answer (score 2):

It is an important ingredient in proofs of embedding results. One standard way of proving these is:

1. Prove the embedding for $W^{1,p}_0(V)$ using density of $C_c^\infty(V)$ functions.
2. Take $u\in W^{1,p}(U)$, extend it to $Eu\in W^{1,p}_0(V)$. Then use the already established embedding result on $Eu$ and carry it over to $u$.